# Nested condtionals in dplyr ifelse statement

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am using `dplyr` and `ifelse` to create a new column based on two conditionals with the data below.

```
dat <- structure(list(GenIndID = c("BHS_034", "BHS_034", "BHS_068", 
"BHS_068", "BHS_068", "BHS_068", "BHS_068", "BHS_068", "BHS_068", 
"BHS_068", "BHS_068"), IndID = c("BHS_034_A", "BHS_034_A", "BHS_068_A", 
"BHS_068_A", "BHS_068_A", "BHS_068_A", "BHS_068_A", "BHS_068_A", 
"BHS_068_A", "BHS_068_A", "BHS_068_A"), Fate = c("Mort", "Mort", 
"Alive", "Alive", "Alive", "Alive", "Alive", "Alive", "Alive", 
"Alive", "Alive"), Status = c("Alive", "Mort", "Alive", "Alive", 
"MIA", "Alive", "MIA", "Alive", "MIA", "Alive", "Alive"), Type = c("Linked", 
"Linked", "SOB", "SOB", "SOB", "SOB", "SOB", "SOB", "SOB", "SOB", 
"SOB"), SurveyID = c("GYA13-1", "GYA14-1", "GYA13-1", "GYA14-1", 
"GYA14-2", "GYA15-1", "GYA16-1", "GYA16-2", "GYA17-1", "GYA17-3", 
"GYA15-2"), SurveyDt = structure(c(1379570400, 1407477600, 1379570400, 
1407477600, 1409896800, NA, 1462946400, 1474351200, 1495519200, 
1507010400, 1441951200), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
))), row.names = c(NA, 11L), .Names = c("GenIndID", "IndID", 
"Fate", "Status", "Type", "SurveyID", "SurveyDt"), class = "data.frame")

> dat
   GenIndID     IndID  Fate Status   Type SurveyID   SurveyDt
1   BHS_034 BHS_034_A  Mort  Alive Linked  GYA13-1 2013-09-19
2   BHS_034 BHS_034_A  Mort   Mort Linked  GYA14-1 2014-08-08
3   BHS_068 BHS_068_A Alive  Alive    SOB  GYA13-1 2013-09-19
4   BHS_068 BHS_068_A Alive  Alive    SOB  GYA14-1 2014-08-08
5   BHS_068 BHS_068_A Alive    MIA    SOB  GYA14-2 2014-09-05
6   BHS_068 BHS_068_A Alive  Alive    SOB  GYA15-1       <NA>
7   BHS_068 BHS_068_A Alive    MIA    SOB  GYA16-1 2016-05-11
8   BHS_068 BHS_068_A Alive  Alive    SOB  GYA16-2 2016-09-20
9   BHS_068 BHS_068_A Alive    MIA    SOB  GYA17-1 2017-05-23
10  BHS_068 BHS_068_A Alive  Alive    SOB  GYA17-3 2017-10-03
11  BHS_068 BHS_068_A Alive  Alive    SOB  GYA15-2 2015-09-11
```

More specifically, grouping by `GenIndID` I want to make a new date field that is the max `SurveyDt` based on a two conditionals for `Type` and `Fate`. Additionally, I want the max date to only evaluate `SurveyDt` when `Status == Alive`. My code below produces all `NA` values, rather than the described date field for `BHS_068` which meets all of the specified conditionals.

I recently saw `case_when` which may be appropriate here, but I could not implement it correctly.

```
dat %>% group_by(GenIndID) %>%
  mutate(NewDat = as.POSIXct(ifelse(Type == "SOB" & Fate == "Alive", max(SurveyDt[Status == "Alive"], na.rm = F), NA), 
                             origin='1970-01-01', na.rm=T)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a table showing how the desired output would look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with `dplyr` and use `case_when` you'll have to make sure than your values for each of the case statements are the same type.

In this case your TRUE value will be datetime, so you have to make the default value a datetime as well by wrapping it in `as.POSIXct`.

```
dat %>%
  group_by(GenIndID) %>%
  mutate(NewDat = case_when(Type == "SOB" & Fate == "Alive" ~ max(SurveyDt[Status == "Alive"], na.rm = TRUE),
                            TRUE ~ as.POSIXct(NA, origin = "1970-01-01")))
```

Using `ifelse`

```
dat %>%
  group_by(GenIndID) %>%
  mutate(NewDat = ifelse(Type == "SOB" & Fate == "Alive", 
                         max(SurveyDt[Status == "Alive"], na.rm = TRUE), 
                         as.POSIXct(NA, origin = "1970-01-01")))
```

Comment: I am not tied to `case_when` if the same result is possible with `ifelse` as I am more familiar with that syntax.

Comment: For `case_when` is the `TRUE ~ as.POSIXct(NA, origin = "1970-01-01"` providing the `else` portion of an `ifelse`? That is, the fill for the rows where the specified conditions are not met. I was not able to interpret this from the help file (with my r ability...).

Answer (score 1):

We could use `data.table`.  After converting to data.table (`setDT(dat)`), specify the `i` as the logical comparison, grouped by 'GenIndID', we assign (`:=`), the `max` of 'SurveyDt' where the 'Status' is "Alive" to 'NewDat'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[Type == "SOB" & Fate == "Alive",
         NewDat := max(SurveyDt[Status == "Alive"], na.rm = TRUE), GenIndID]
```